# Reset asynchronous UIImageView before loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uitableview

My application hierarchy is as follows:

```
UINavigationController
|_____
      UITableViewController (display products summary with thumbnail image)
      |_____
            UIViewController (display product details with image)
```

I'm using the following class to load images asynchronously in both UITableViewController and UIViewController since it was too slow to load the view as its getting the image from the internet

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image

I don't have any problem in UITableViewController, the problem is when the cell is clicked it loads the image in UIViewController, if I go back to UITableViewController then click another cell, the UIViewController opened with previous image until the new image loaded

How can I reset the UIImageView in UIViewController until the new image loaded?

This is the code to load the details view:

```
CGRect frame;
frame.size.width=240; frame.size.height=130;
frame.origin.x=0; frame.origin.y=0;
AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
asyncImage.tag = 999;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i53.tinypic.com/5ezwc4.jpg"];
[asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];
[detailsViewController.imgProduct addSubview:asyncImage];
```

Please help.

Comment: Post the code where detailsviewcontroller is created. You may probably want to remove the asyncImage from it or create the controller afresh when tableview is tapped.

Comment: the detail view controller is created in IB, the reason behind the asyncImage in the details view is because it was too slow to open the details view as its reading the image from the internet

Answer (score 1):

This is bz in the loadimagefromurl method of the AsyncImageview method which cached u r prev data , u need a reset cache - to set its

```
    imageCache = nil; in the method
```

But it will affect other viewcontrollers using asynimageview ,

I hope u have single image in u r detailsview controller so

Better i should suggest to use GCD for this

```
NSString *finalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/no-image-available.png"];    

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{


    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:finalStr];

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



    UIImage *img01 = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];


    imgView.image = img01;  
    });
```

});

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/

this will give you same performance

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan, from what I understood is that GCD will help in  table view cells which I don't have any problem, where my problem is only when loading the details view where its image is not reset while the new image is loading!

Comment: I tried to place imageCache = nil in but it throw an error! This is loadImageFromURL: -(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url { [connection release]; [data release]; NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]; connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; }

Answer (score 0):

It worth enhancing the AsyncImageView class. Add your own init method, like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The file loading.png must be in your bundle and contain something proper to show while the remote image is loading.

Comment: Thanks Slava, I placed this method in AsynchImageView.m but I got the following error: Semantic Issue: Setter method is needed to assign to object using property assignment syntax

Comment: Try the remote image from [here](https://github.com/iutinvg/ZZLib/tree/master/ZZLib) See files `ZZImageView.*` and `loading.png` And dont't forget to include imported files (see header of `ZZImageView.m`).